# Angular material; How to change mat-menu background color programmatically?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have this piece of code for my mega menu:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="objectmenu">Objects</button>
        <mat-menu #objectmenu="matMenu" >
              <div class="menu-content" [style.backgroundColor]="getUnSelectedRandomColor()" style="height: 550px;">
                <div  fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="30" fxFlex.sm="45" class="dropdown-menu-items"> 
                  <div class="dropdown-menu-btns" *ngFor="let parent of (objectList$ | async)"
                   (mouseover)="openCategory($event, 
                   parent)"
                   [style.background-color] = "this.selectedColor === (parent.categoryId * 100)  ? getSelectedRandomColor() : getUnSelectedRandomColor()"

                   >{{parent.name}}</div>
              </div>
                    <div class="theme-container">

                    <div class="theme-container" style=" padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-top: 7px !important;">
                      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="content border-lighter">
                        <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"> 
                            <h2 *ngIf="this.selectedCategory" class="uppercase">{{this.selectedCategory.name}}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content border-lighter" [style.backgroundColor]="getSelectedRandomColor()" style="height: 380px;">

                        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between"> 
                            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="70" fxFlex.sm="45" style="column-count: 2;"> 
                              <ul class="ht-dropdown megamenu-two d-flex"
                              *ngFor="let parent of (childCategories$ | async)" style="list-style: none;">

                               <label [routerLink]="['/products']" [queryParams]="{categories: parent.categoryId}"
                               routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{parent.name}}</label>
                             <li *ngFor="let child of parent.childrenCategories"
                             [routerLink]="['/products']" [queryParams]="{categories: child.categoryId}"
                               routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
                               {{child.name}}

                           </li>
                         </ul>
                            </div>



                            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="30" ngClass.lt-md="pt-5" style="background-size: contain !important;"
                            [style.background]="selectedCategoryUrl"> 

                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </div>


                    </div> 
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
                      <img *ngFor="let brand of (relatedBrandsList$ | async)"  [src]=" brand.thumbnail | safeHtml" style="width: 110px; height: 110px; border-radius: 50%;"/>
                    </div>                     
                  </div>                    
                 </div>   


        </mat-menu>
```

and it gives me the following style:
[image]

As shown in the picture, the top and the bottom edges of the menu panel are not taking the dynamic background color which I generate in my angular code by getUnSelectedRandomColor() method.
The getUnSelectedRandomColor() method is as follow:

```
openCategory(evt, category: Category) {
    this.selectedCategory = category;
    this.selectedCategoryUrl = `url('../../assets/categories/${category.categoryId}.webp')`;
    this.childCategories$ = this.store.pipe(select(getChildCategories(category.categoryId)));
    this.relatedBrandsList$ = this.store.pipe(select(getRelatedBrands(category.categoryId)));
    this.selectedColor = category.categoryId * 100;
    }

  getSelectedRandomColor() {
    const color = 'hsl(' + this.selectedColor + ', 30%, 75%)';
    return color;
    }
  getUnSelectedRandomColor() {
      const color = 'hsl(' + this.selectedColor + ', 30%, 86%)';
      return color;
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Add `console.log('this.selectedColor:', this.selectedColor);` inside `getUnSelectedRandomColor()` to verify that it's not `undefined` when called.

Comment: I know it works because the current background color shown in the picture is returned by this method

Comment: Which elements in the markup represent the top and bottom edges?

Comment: The mat-menu tag which is in line 2 of the markup code. I tried putting getUnSelectedRandomColor() in that line also but again no use.

Comment: I don't know if your markup complies with material menu structure. In the documentation I see that the direct children of `<mat-menu>` are `<button mat-menu-item>` elements. Anyway best if you could upload your code to StackBlitz.

Comment: Thank you dear Benny, I found the solution

Comment: So will we see this question marked as resolved? It seems that some thought it was worth the time invested. Probably worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Angular 9**

What happens is that you are not affecting the menu panel item, you must get the panelId which is a property of MatMenu, with the panel id you get the element and then change the value of the attribute you want, to achieve this you can use property decorator that configures a view query ViewChild and the service Renderer2.

Here I show you an example in which I dynamically change the background of the panel according to the menu item that emits the mouseover [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-mat-menu-background-color-programmatically)

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenu } from '@angular/material/menu/';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('menu', {static: true}) menu: MatMenu

  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2) {
  }

  changeBackgroundPanel(colorValue: string) {
    const el = document.getElementById(this.menu.panelId);
    this._renderer2.setStyle(el, 'background', colorValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" color="primary">Open Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('blue')">Blue</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('orange')">Orange</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('red')">Red</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**[Solution for Angular 8]**

See the example working here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8-change-mat-menu-background-color-programmatically)

Component:

```js
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2) {
  }

  changeBackgroundPanel(colorValue: string) {
    const el = document.getElementById('myPanelId');
    this._renderer2.setStyle(el, 'background', colorValue);
  }
}
```

Html:

```html
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" color="primary">Open Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div id="myPanelId" class="menu-panel">
    <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('blue')">Blue</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('orange')">Orange</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (mouseover)="changeBackgroundPanel('red')">Red</button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

CSS:

```css
.menu-panel {
  margin: -8px 0; 
  padding: 8px 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using angular 8 and I dont have panelId property for menu. How can I access it؟ the error is: Property 'panelId' does not exist on type 'MatMenu'

Comment: Edit the answer to show how it could be done in angular 8, I realized that the way it is done in angular 8 it can also be done in angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer:

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-content{
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
          }
```

I removed the paddings using the above style and then the white gaps were removed

Comment: The use of :: ng-deep is deprecated the solution now is encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in the component decorator and use the style like this .customClass { .mat-menu-content{ } } look more here https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-overlay-components